# Steam not opening or responding at all

Tags: 12.10, steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I report bugs/problems with Valve’s Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236773/where-do-i-report-bugs-problems-with-valves-steam)

The steam client won't open nor does it display any error message.
I have tried `right click > Games`. I ran `steam steam://open/games` command, but the client just does not respond. Removing it with `apt-get remove steam`, deleting the Steam directory & the .deb file and reinstalling it, did not work either.

This problem only occurred after I used `killall steam.sh` to force quit it, it was working fine before.

I'm running 12.10 on a 64bit laptop with no additional drivers installed.

Anyone else have this problem and a possible workaround?

Thank you

Comment: Steam is currently in a limited beta - you will probably have more luck resolving this by reporting it on the steam community for linux forums.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution on the Steam [forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/882966056531786801/#p4), post #55, solution described below:

This was done on a laptop with **Intel HD graphics**, not sure if this will work with NVidia or AMD drivers.

1.) Purge Steam PPA `sudo apt-get --purge remove steam:i386`

2.) Delete all Steam files from /home, including the two .steam files

3.) Download and install `wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb` and `sudo dpkg -i steam.deb && sudo apt-get install -f`

4.) It should update and install Steam now, enter your username and password. Steam is going to tell you that you are not a beta tester and quit the application.

5.) Run in terminal `steam steam://open/games`

6.) Steam client should be up and running

Answer (score 0):

I do also have this issue. Steam wont start...

I removed the `Steam dir` from `home` and tried to start it from a `terminal`. It wanted to install `jockey-common` and `nvidia-common`. Try installing them and try again.