# Where do I report bugs/problems with Valve's Steam?

Tags: steam

I have a problem with Steam or one of it's games, how do I report this to Valve?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Valve](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/blob/master/README.md):

> If you encounter an issue while using Steam for Linux or with any of
>   the available Linux games, first search the issue list to see if it
>   has already been reported. Include closed issues in your search.
>
> If it has not been reported, create a new issue with at least the
>   following information:
>
> - a short, descriptive title;
> - a detailed description of the issue, including any output from the command line;
> - steps for reproducing the issue; and
> - your system information.

- [List of existing issues](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues)
- [Link to file a new issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/new), you will need a [github account](https://github.com/).