# Steam not booting up?

Tags: steam

Maybe it's because of the driver?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an HP Pavilion dv7 with a Radeon video card.

```
steam
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
downloader@downloader:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2013-09-05 20:33:10] Startup - updater built Aug 28 2013 13:29:34
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1377723241_client)
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1377723241_client)
[2013-09-05 20:33:10] Checking for update on startup
[2013-09-05 20:33:10] Checking for available updates...
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1377723241_client)
[2013-09-05 20:33:11] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1377723241, installed version 1377723241
[2013-09-05 20:33:11] Nothing to do
[2013-09-05 20:33:11] Verifying installation...
[2013-09-05 20:33:11] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2013-09-05 20:33:11] Verification complete
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 3364 with name 0eBlobRegistryMutex_C1F8136AD979A434C95ECA754B1635A0
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 3364 with name 0eBlobRegistrySignal_C1F8136AD979A434C95ECA754B1635A0
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 3364 with name 0emSteamEngineInstance
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 3364 with name 0eSteamEngineLock
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display
```

And here's the bit of information asked..

```
downloader@downloader:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA and glxinfo | grep -i render
grep: and: No such file or directory
grep: glxinfo: No such file or directory
downloader@downloader:~$ apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
libgl1-mesa-dri:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6
  Version table:
     8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     8.0.2-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
libgl1-mesa-glx:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6
  Version table:
     8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     8.0.2-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
downloader@downloader:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This might be [a Steam bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236773/where-do-i-report-bugs-problems-with-valves-steam). You might want to report it as one, but I believe @Braiam may have some other valuable ideas for it.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA` and `glxinfo | grep -i render`, also `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx`

Comment: hmm no I can't...because "no such file or directory" for all of the above, @Braiam.

Answer (score 0):

Reading Braiam comment I think you should have executed the commands in three steps:

First one: *lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA*

Second one: *glxinfo | grep -i render*

Third one: *apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx*

Comment: hm okay. well I did that, only the second line worked. I edited the field again to reflect it.

Comment: ohh my, sorry the first one I pointed is also two commands:
"lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA" and the other "glxinfo | grep -i render"