# Civilization V won't start

Tags: steam, 14.10

I just bought and downloaded "Sid Meier's Civilization V: Complete Edition". I have downloaded it and when I click play the "Preparing to launch" dialogue box appears then disappears and nothing it launched.

I also installed a 8-bit MMO and it launches and works fine.

Running Ubuntu 14.10

- Chip: CPU T2400 @ 1.83GHz × 2
- Graphics: Intel® 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
- 32-bit architecture
- 2.5gb of RAM
- SSD hard drive if that makes a difference

This the output when I run it from the command line:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8750439/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8750458/

According to this vitorgatti
On this thread https ://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3561 
The graphics card is not compatible
:(

Comment: You mean "Sid Meier's Civilization V"? Then please open a terminal wiht Ctrl + Shift + t and start the game with `steam steam://rungameid/8930` add the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ click the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/543738/edit) link below your question and add the pastebin link.

Comment: Yeah it is "Sid Meier's Civilization V"

Comment: Do you have a Nvidia Optimus installed on this computer?

Comment: No, Should I?  ..

Comment: Well, does your integrated graphic have 500MB of RAM? Because I can't tell of the limited info you've given us...

Comment: @nicxcin To bad :(. So one of the minimum requirement didn't match I guess? Would you mind accepting one answer and thus close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** Valve is responsible for the Steam client, Fireaxis for the PC Release of this Game. I've added a how to [report to Aspyr](https://askubuntu.com/a/544094/75166) which fits the problem better than this answer.

### Report it to Valve

You can [report this problem to Valve](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236773/where-do-i-report-bugs-problems-with-valves-steam) . They already have listed [a similiar issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3353) but I'm not sure what to make of it.

Since I can't seem to find any indication in the terminal output as to why the game stops. You might need to:

### Report it to Fireaxis

[Fireaxis](http://www.firaxis.com/) has a [Community](http://www.civfanatics.com/) lisiting its [known and confirmed bugs](http://forums.civfanatics.com/forumdisplay.php?f=415). Here is [how to report a bug](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=380293):

> 1. Look through this forum to see if it has been Confirmed as a bug. If so, you can reply in that thread to that effect, and add your own view, screenshot or save file.
> 2. If you CAN'T find it in this forum, please post about it in the [main Bug Reports Forum](http://forums.civfanatics.com/forumdisplay.php?f=390).

Comment: Thanks I will try that now, Installing Nvidia optimus broke my system so I have downgraded to 14.04

Comment: @nicxcin I'm sorry to hear that :-(

Answer (score 2):

### Check if you fulfill the minimal requirements

[Aspyr](http://www.aspyr.com/) has done the [porting](https://steamcommunity.com/app/8930/discussions/0/540743758002415316/?l=german) of "Sid Meier's Civilization V: Complete Edition" for Linux. The minimum requirements for Linux for the Linux Steam version are:

> Check that your video card is running OpenGL version 3.3 with at least 512MB of Vram.

To be sure that you fulfill the requirements. They say

> Select Help from the Steam menu, then System Information.

[Source](http://support.aspyr.com/entries/46384334-Not-launching-or-graphic-corruption-) (If you want to read it, you **will** need sign-up for an account at their support system. It's easy, at no cost and looks serious.)

### Report it to Aspyr

If you fulfill the requirements and you still can't start the game you should open a ticket.

> Open a ticket with us (support@aspyr.com) and include a copy/paste of the Steam System information screen.

[Same Source as above](http://support.aspyr.com/entries/46384334-Not-launching-or-graphic-corruption-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with the game launching on Linux (and you have a updated drivers and graphics card that support Open GL 3.3+), disconnect additional monitors and set your screen to a 16:9 aspect ratio resolution.  You'll need to do this every time you want to play the game.  This is a common problem with the Linux version.

If the above didn't solve your issue and you are running the game via Steam, you may need to change the game's launch options.  For your launch options, use:

`MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.1 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=140 %command%`

If you are having audio issues, edit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf and modify the following settings with these new values (however you may need to try different fragment-size-msec value):

`default-fragments = 5 default-fragment-size-msec = 25`

Then kill and restart PulseAudio:

`pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start`

*Sources:*

[Civ 5 - Game won't start, not presenting errors](http://steamcommunity.com/app/8930/discussions/1/540744299927655197/#p4)

[Civ 5 - Linux audio problems](http://steamcommunity.com/app/8930/discussions/1/540744299662467088?l=czech#p4)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news:

Your problem is that you are trying to run a 64 bit executable on a 32 bit install of Ubuntu.

Unfortunately your CPU isn't 64bit:
http://ark.intel.com/m/products/27235/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2400-2M-Cache-1_83-GHz-667-MHz-FSB#@product/specifications

Unless they have a 32 bit version of the program available your only option to get it working is to upgrade your CPU and install Ubuntu 64bit.

In the meantime:
    sudo apt-get install wesnoth

Comment: Do you think it won't run on 32-bit CPU because of the message in the pastebin: "ERROR: ld.so: object ... LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored."? I have the same error on my 64-bit machine and this still runs perfectly. I don't think its the reason the game doesn't run.

Comment: I didn't notice ignored at the end of the message... If it is an error which can happen on a working installation, I may be wrong.

Comment: It **doesn't** run on my 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 laptop. The output seems to be about the same as the pastebin.

Comment: The game was originally developed for 32-bit Windows. This **should** be working for 32-bit Linux too.

Comment: Should I try wine?

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21465

Comment: Apparently it CAN be run in wine, but will freeze if you press any key on your keyboard. . . probably not the playing experience you would  want.

Comment: @MadMike it all depends on which architectures they decide to destribute it for. I agree with you that there is no reason a 32bit version shouldn't be possible